# if element exist on document then add an addittional value into method

Tags: javascript, resize

I really need some help with this, I dont know javascript well at all to be honest, a friend of mine put some of this together a few months ago ive just added $contentContainer and added these variables but I just need one more thing added to if for it to suite my needs...

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // DOM Container Resize Handler
                var adjustStyle = function() {
                    var winWidth = $(window).width(),
                        width = parseInt(winWidth),
                        container = $('body .fixed');
                        contentContainer = $('body .content');
                    if (width >= 1454) {
                        container.css('width','1454px');
                        contentContainer.css('width','1210px');
                    } else if ((width < 1454) & (width >= 1212)) {
                        container.css('width','1212px');
                        contentContainer.css('width','968px');
                    } else {
                       container.css('width','970px');
                       contentContainer.css('width','726px');
                    }
                };
                 $(function() {
                    var filterWrap = $("#filterWrap"),
                        offset = filterWrap.offset(),
                        topPadding = 15;

                    $(window).scroll(function() {
                        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                            filterWrap.stop().animate({
                                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                            });
                        } else {
                            filterWrap.stop().animate({
                                marginTop: 0
                            });
                        };
                    });

                    // DOM Container Resize Handler - Initialization    
                    $(window).resize(function() {
                        adjustStyle();
                    });
                    adjustStyle();
                });
            </script>
```

I need to modify this script to search through the document and IF document DOES NOT contain ('body .asideContent') to add 252px to the object contentContainer.css method

Don't worry about the fileerWrap function this works fine :)

I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this :)

```
if($("body.asideContent").length === 0){
  var width = contentContainer.css('width');
  contentContainer.css('width',width + 252 + "px");  
}
```

Comment: Hey thank ou for your help, but I cant seems to get it working... not sure why... but for example

see this in my code:

contentContainer.css('width','968px');

what I want is if($("body.asideContent").length === 0)

then the result would be 

contentContainer.css('width','968px'); +252  if document does contain ("body.asideContent") then it would work as it always does... so not sure but I don't think your changes work, useless its how im implementing it :S